# idangerous SwiperJS - In free Mode show only last single slide instead of 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, swiper.js

**DEMO -** https://codepen.io/syedazam/pen/YzPRxQQ?editors=1000

I am working on a swiper js by idangerous, which is working fine.

I am using `freemode:true` for smooth scrolling with `loop:false`

now the thing is when ever i reach to the last slide, i need to display only one slide (single slide) instead of 3.

Request you guys to shed some light.. i have the code in codepen for your reference.

**swiper code :**

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 3.2,
  spaceBetween: 20, 
  slidesPerGroup: 3,
  draggable:true,
  snapOnRelease:true, 
  loop: false,
  loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
  speed: 1100,
  shortSwipes:true,
  grabCursor: true,
  slidesPerViewFit: false,
  effect: 'slide',
  stopOnLastSlide:true,
  /* pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },*/
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  },  
   on: {
    init: function () {
      console.log('do something */');
    },
   }
});
swiper.on('reachEnd', function () {
  console.log('last slide ');
});
```